# Visual Studio 2017 - can't create an Azure Function app

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2017 and try to add Azure Function app to this solution:

[image]

but when I click "Ok" I get an error:

> Method not found: 'Void
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.CommonUI.Controls.CommonGlyphs.ConfigureCloseButton(System.Windows.Controls.Button)'

and it creates an empty folder "FunctionApp1", without any data inside. Why and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools installed?

Comment: What version of Azure Functions and Web Jobs for Visual Studio do you have? The latest is v1.0.12.

Comment: @ConnorMcMahon, I have v15.0.40322.0 from 26 march 2018 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As M0rty mentioned that you could try to update `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`.

If reinstall the `Azure development` is possible, you could reinstall it and try again.

You also could get detail steps from [Azure Functions Tools for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs).

Comment: you are right (almost :) ), problem was in update of Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Visual Studio updates.